# Iterate through a generic List java

Tags: java

Hi I am stuck at how to iterate through a generic list using iterator.

for example i hve something like this:

```
public class a{
     protected int _b;
     protected String _c;
     protected float _d;
     protected int _e;
public a(int b, String c, float d, int e){
            // assign value _b,_c,_d,_e
}

     static class ab implement Iterable<a>{
           public static List myList = new ArrayList(a);
           public static void addlist(a f){
                   myList.add(f);
           public Iterator<a> iterator(){
                   return myList.iterator()}// overriding List iterator method
```

then in main method i assign value for _b,_c,_d,_e by creating instances of class a and add it to myList but when i use the iterator it doesnt show the list but it shows the memory location( i guess)of that list. I want it to show all the field in class a one by one. any suggestion what i should do ???

Comment: It looks to me that you should have `new ArrayList<a>()` rather than `new ArrayList(a)`. One creates an `ArrayList` of `a` whilst the other creates an `ArrayList` _containing_ `a`. This is either a typo or the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `toString()` method in Class `a` .

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "_b:"+_b+",_c:"+_c+"_d:"+_d+",_e:"+_e;
 }
```

If `toString()` is not overridden then , your Class `a` uses the inherited one from Class `Object` :

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Comment: What if i wanna use enhanced for-loop to loop through the list then use print to display it ??

Comment: @TommyNgo How do you mean?

Comment: Please let me know in which manner you want to print ? `System.out.println(instance of a)` will always look for the `toString()` of class `a` , either inherited or overridden . So you need to override that if you want to directly print the instance of `a` meaningfully .

Comment: Other ways are i)define getters for the protected instance variables or ii) define a public method inside `a` which will print all the instance variables . When you loop through the list for each instance of `a` i) print all the getters , ii) call the public display method.

Comment: Inside the class `a` define a public method : `public void display() { System.out.println("_b:"+_b+",_c:"+_c+"_d:"+_d+",_e:"+_e); }` and call it when you iterate through the list , for example :  `a instanceOfA = iterator.next(); instanceOfA.display();`

Answer (score 2):

`it doesnt show the list but it shows the memory location( i guess)of that list.`.

It is showing the memory location because you have not overridden the `toString` method, so it is falling back on the default `Object` implementation. You need to override the `toString` method in your `a` class.

If you add something like:

```
public String toString()
{
    return // Some string data. 
}
```

To your `a` class, you'll start seeing correct outputs.

**Note**: Java naming convention states that all classes should start with a capital letter, and have a capital letter for every word. ie: `a -> A`.